# validar datos de un objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array, validación, objeto

mi html

```
<form action="" class="formulario">
    <label><p>Ingrese su ci: <input type="text"  id="cedulaaa" required autofocus placeholder="25000111" maxlength="10" ></p></label>
    
        <p>
          <input type="reset" value="Restaurar">
          <input type="submit" onClick="esValido()" value="Acceder" id="aaceder">
        </p>
      </form>
```

mi javascript

```
function validacioon() {
  let datos = {"cedulas":["25000111", "21000222", "22444333", "23222333", "25111222"]};
  let cedula = document.getElementById("cedulaaa").value; //permite el acceso a un elemento por su id
  let arrays = Object.values(datos)
  return arrays.includes(cedula)
       } 
      function esValido() {
      let valides = validacioon()
     if (valides === true){
     alert( "exacto" );}}
```

me gustaria validar este objeto JSON y no me valida porque tengo entendido que con el Object.values lo recorro y me devuelve los valores en un array y luego le estoy metiendo en el retorno el includes para que me devuelva un booleano porfavor me gustaria una ayudita para ver que esta mal o si le falta algo.

Comment: `let arrays = Object.values(datos)` estás obteniendo un arreglo del objeto completo y necesitas solo las cedulas: `let arrays = Object.values(datos.cedulas)`,

Comment: Nisiquiera necesita usar `Object.values`, pues como solo necesita los valores de esa propiedad podria ser entonces: `let arrays = datos.cedulas`, queda mucho mas corto y no haces que javascript tenga que construir un array con todos los valores de las propiedades del objeto.

Comment: Muy cierto, @Riven, comenté muy a la ligera. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia esta linea:

```
let arrays = Object.values(datos)
```

por esta:

```
let arrays = datos.cedulas;
```

Pues tu solo necesitas hacer la comprobacion con el arreglo de cedulas, por lo tanto no necesitas ponerte a sacar los values de todas las propiedades del objeto.

Esto que he hecho es mucho mas corto y arregla el error.

Pero para que entiendas mejor el porque esto no funciona:

```
let arrays = Object.values(datos)
```

Es simplemente porque recuerda que `Object.values`, te devuelve en un **array**, los values de cada una de las propiedades de un `Object`, por tanto al hacer:

```
Object.values(datos);
```

Lo que enrealidad estarias obteniendo **NO** es:

```
["25000111", "21000222", "22444333", "23222333", "25111222"]
```

Si no:

```
[["25000111", "21000222", "22444333", "23222333", "25111222"]]
```

Porque en este caso el value de nuestra propiedad cedulas es un array entero.

Por lo tanto si quisieras que tu codigo funcionara pero usando `Object.values` tendrias que primero acceder a la pocision `[0]`, que contendría todas las cedulas:

```
let arrays = Object.values(datos)[0];
```

Pero claro, esto solo funcionaria si tu `Object` esta en orden de tal manera que su primera propiedad sea `cedulas`, pues si hay mas propiedades los valores del object diferiran en orden.

Comment: muchas gracias compañero Riven me aclaraste todo, me quitaste un dolor de cabeza pórque tenia muchas horas intentanto ver porque no validaba, eres todo un heroe sigue asi :)